# How should I access the attributes of a model in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-models

I'm trying to show users the product variations that they have selected. While the code is working and saving the variation in the database, I am not being able to show them on my html page. Only `:` is being rendered. What is the problem? Is the way I'm calling it wrong? This is what I've tried:

My models.py:

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    variation_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=VAR_TYPES, default='Size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = VariationManager()

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item  = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)
```

My order_summary.html:

```
{% for order_item in object.items.all %}
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="border-0">
        <div class="p-2">
          <img src="{{ order_item.item.image_url }}" alt="" width="70" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm">
            <div class="ml-3 d-inline-block align-middle">
              <h5 class="mb-0"> <a href="{{ order_item.item.get_absolute_url }}" class="text-dark d-inline-block align-middle">{{ order_item.item.title }}</a>
              {% if order_item.variation %}
               <ul>
                 <h6>{{ order_item.variation.variation_type }} : {{ order_item.variation.title }}</h6>
               </ul>
             {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
       </th>
```

My views.py:

```
class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'orders/order_summary.html', context)

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")
```

Comment: You should show views.py of the corresponding page.

Comment: I've added my views now

Comment: Is there Order model or OrderItem?

Comment: Yes there is order model OrderItem model

Comment: Both are there and I've added a manytomanyfield relation to variation in both of them

Comment: Can you check by putting else part in ```order_item.variation.all``` ?

Comment: It is already `order_item.variation.all`

Comment: It goes from if part right??

Comment: In my order-summary.html I've written : `{% if order_item.variation.all %}`. and `{% for subitem in order_item.variation.all %}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213087/discussion-between-biplove-lamichhane-and-abrar).

Comment: If I try `{{ order_item.variation.all }}` and it gives an empty queryset
like : `<QuerySet []>`
And if I try `{{ order_item.variation }}`, it says : `products.Variation.None`.
What is the problem?